# Casper JS gets stuck when clicked

Tags: javascript, forms, phantomjs, casperjs

I am new to `casperJS` and I am trying to fill out the form. When I click the button by `this.click('input[type="button"][value="Add"][class="ui-btn-hidden"]');`
I see some out put in my console that is the console output on click of the button e.g [image]

I am seeing the same output in my terminal and my script gets stuck and I see the error `Wait timeout of 10000ms expired, exiting.`

How can I skip to the next step after the click has been performed without waiting for the output?

**EDIT**
My code is

```
casper.then(function () {


    this.evaluate(function () {
        if (!$('#add-button').is(':visible')){
            this.echo("add button visible");
            $('#yourHeader').click();
            this.echo("add button clicked");
        }
        $('#add-header').click();
        this.echo("add header clicked");
    });
    this.waitUntilVisible('input[id="newAmount"]');

    this.capture(CapturePath('add_form.png'));
    this.evaluate(function () {

        $("#newType option:contains('Direct')").prop('selected', true).change();
        this.echo(" type selected");
    });
    this.capture(CapturePath('filledForm.png'));
    this.sendKeys('input[id="newAmount"]', Balance);
    this.echo("new amount set as "+loanBalance);
    this.capture(CapturePath('filledFormamount.png'));
    this.sendKeys('input[id="newInterest"]', interestRate);
    this.echo("new interest rate set as "+interestRate);
    this.capture(CapturePath('filledFormInterest.png'));
    this.echo('clicking ui-btn-hidden');
    this.click('input[type="button"][value="Add"][class="ui-btn-hidden"]');


    this.capture(CapturePath('CompletedForm.png'));

    this.capture(CapturePath('selectFound.png'));
    this.echo("here I am");
});

casper.run(function () {
    this.echo('Done').exit();
});
```

I never see Done with this code

Comment: Please show a minimal working example of your code. The error seems to be related to waiting for something and there isn't even a hint about that in your question.

Comment: @Vaviloff please see my edit